# How can I remove all text after a character in bash?

Tags: bash

How can I remove all text after a character, in this case a colon (":"), in bash? Can I remove the colon, too? I have no idea how to.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

An example might have been useful, but if I understood you correctly, this would work:

```
echo "Hello: world" | cut -f1 -d":"
```

This will convert `Hello: world` into `Hello`.

Comment: `cut` works, but I Dennis' answer is better and more flexible. Does anyone know if it spawns a new process like `cut`?

Comment: It's better to use Bash's built-in parameter expansion features than generating subshells running tools like `basename` and `cut`, see Dennis's answer below

Comment: `cut` can read from stdin,  so it is better especially when you have a very long string that you need to process, like the contents of a file.

Comment: And how would this be applied to `hello: world`. This is half an answer.

Comment: It can be done using subsitution syntax also like {var/:/''}, but works only in bash..

Comment: What if you have a string "Hello: world: this: is: me: again" and you want to truncate everything after the LAST occurrence of the ":", given that you do NOT know how many ":" characters are in the string. So here I would want the output to be "Hello: world: this: is: me". How would you do that?

Answer (score 419):

In Bash (and ksh, zsh, dash, etc.), you can use parameter expansion with `%` which will remove characters from the end of the string or `#` which will remove characters from the beginning of the string. If you use a single one of those characters, the smallest matching string will be removed. If you double the character, the longest will be removed.

```
$ a='hello:world'

$ b=${a%:*}
$ echo "$b"
hello

$ a='hello:world:of:tomorrow'

$ echo "${a%:*}"
hello:world:of

$ echo "${a%%:*}"
hello

$ echo "${a#*:}"
world:of:tomorrow

$ echo "${a##*:}"
tomorrow
```

Comment: This is native shell string manipulation, so no additional processes will be spawned. Reference [Bash Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF), [Bash String Manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and [Better Bash Scripting](http://robertmuth.blogspot.jp/2012/08/better-bash-scripting-in-15-minutes.html)

Comment: @denniswilliamson How could I deleted 2 characters after a specific string like `hello:world` will become `hello:wo` by using `${a%:*}`?

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot, but it will be nice to also add `"${a##*:}"` for getting only `tomorrow` =)

Comment: Nice. How should I nest these commands? I tried `a=path/to/file_v1.ext; echo "${a##*/%_*}"`, but I didn't get the desired `file`

Comment: @SibbsGambling: They can't be nested. They have to be done as a sequence of separate operations.

Comment: I am trying to remove _(digit)_ from _word(digit)_ to get only _word_, when using `str="word(5)"`, the `str="${str%(*}"` actually seems to add some character, instead of removing "_(5)_". Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @Nazar: You need to escape the open parenthesis, like so: str="${str%\(*}"

Comment: @EldadMor: Your escaping didn't show up, probably because you didn't enclose your code in backticks.

Comment: Is there another possible variation to generate hello:

Comment: @openCivilisation: What are you looking for?

Comment: the example ```echo "${a%%:*}"```
generates ```hello```.  its really close to what I'm after, I'd just like to include the ```:``` if it exists as well to produce ```hello:```

Comment: @openCivilisation: You probably need to use regular expression matching then: `a='hello:world:of:tomorrow'; pattern=''^([^:]*:).*$'`; [[ $a =~ $pattern ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`. That matches only if there is a colon. If you want that to be optional, a different pattern would have to be used. An explanation of Bash regexes (and regexes in general) is beyond the scope of these comments. You can find other questions that discuss this or post your own.

Comment: What if you have a string "Hello: world: this: is: me: again" and you want to truncate everything after the LAST occurrence of the ":", given that you do NOT know how many ":" characters are in the string. So here I would want the output to be "Hello: world: this: is: me". How would you do that?

Comment: @kp123: It's the first example in my answer. The second time I show it (where "tomorrow" is removed), it's almost exactly the situation you're asking about.

Comment: doesn't work for me: `echo ${"https://www.rt.com/news/510303-thailand-outbreak-coronavirus-testing/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=RSS"%\?*}`

Comment: @chovy afaik you need to use variable `a='https://www.rt.com/news/510303-thailand-outbreak-coronavirus-testing/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=RSS'; echo ${a%\?*}`

Answer (score 23):

```
$ echo 'hello:world:again' |sed 's/:.*//'
hello
```

Comment: what if you want the after part?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30352137/1949550

Answer (score 13):

I know some solutions:

```sh
# Our mock data:
A=user:mail:password
```

1. With **awk** and pipe:

```sh
$ echo $A | awk -v FS=':' '{print $1}'
user
```

2. Via **bash variables**:

```sh
$ echo ${A%%:*}
user
```

3. With pipe and **sed**:

```sh
$ echo $A | sed 's#:.*##g'
user
```

4. With pipe and **grep**:

```sh
$ echo $A | egrep -o '^[^:]+'
user
```

5. With pipe and **cut**:

```sh
$ echo $A | cut -f1 -d\: 
user
```

Comment: I like:  echo $A | cut -f1 -d\:    Easy to read!

Answer (score 7):

```
egrep -o '^[^:]*:'
```

Comment: can you explain how to interpret this , Thank you.

Comment: `egrep` is grep with `-E`.  It makes no difference here from regular `grep`.  `-o` instructs grep to print out only the part of the line that matches the expression.  `^` anchors the match to the start of a line.  `[^:]*` matches zero or more characters that are not the `:` character.  `:` matches the character `:`.

Answer (score 4):

trim off everything after the last instance of ":"

```
grep -o '^.*:' fileListingPathsAndFiles.txt
```

and if you wanted to drop that last ":"

```
grep -o '^.*:' file.txt | sed 's/:$//'
```

@kp123: you'd want to replace `:` with `/` (where the sed colon should be `\/`)

Comment: The only correct answer. As this answer removes *after* a specific character given, the other answers remove the character aswell.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a path with a file in this format:

```
/dirA/dirB/dirC/filename.file
```

Now you only want the path which includes four "/". Type

```
$ echo "/dirA/dirB/dirC/filename.file" | cut -f1-4 -d"/"
```

and your output will be

```
/dirA/dirB/dirC
```

The advantage of using cut is that you can also cut out the uppest directory as well as the file (in this example), so if you type

```
$ echo "/dirA/dirB/dirC/filename.file" | cut -f1-3 -d"/"
```

your output would be

```
/dirA/dirB
```

Though you can do the same from the other side of the string, it would not make that much sense in this case as typing

```
$ echo "/dirA/dirB/dirC/filename.file" | cut -f2-4 -d"/"
```

results in

```
dirA/dirB/dirC
```

In some other cases the last case might also be helpful. Mind that there is no "/" at the beginning of the last output.

Comment: What if you have a directory "/resources/views/admin/users/relationships/posts.blade.php" and you want to truncate everything after the LAST occurrence of the "/", given that you do NOT know how many "/" characters are in the string. So here I would want the output to be "/resources/views/admin/users/relationships/" (or even /resources/views/admin/users/relationships without the trailing slash). How would you do that?

Comment: more than a year old; There's a command for that: dirname

Comment: What about if i have a number 19359.364263397103 how do i remove all chars starting with . and all tothe right so all thats left is the left part whats the command look like for that?