# How to delete all text on a line appearing after a particular symbol?

Tags: ruby, perl, bash, sed, python-2.7

I have a file, `file1.txt`, like this:

```
This is some text.
This is some more text. ② This is a note.
This is yet some more text.
```

I need to delete any text appearing after "②", including the "②" and any single space appearing immediately before, if such a space is present. E.g., the above file would become `file2.txt`:

```
This is some text.
This is some more text.
This is yet some more text.
```

How can I delete the "②", anything coming after, and any preceding single space?

- The solutions at [How can I remove all text after a character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168371/how-can-i-remove-all-text-after-a-character-in-bash) do not seem to work, perhaps because "②" is not an ordinary character.
- The file is saved in UTF-8.

Comment: What OS? What encoding of your text?

Answer (score 3):

A Perl solution:

```
$ perl -CS -i~ -p -E's/ ②.*//' file1.txt
```

You'll end up with the correct data in file1.txt and a backup of the original file in file1.txt~.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you do realize most unix utilities do not work with unicode. I assume your input is in UTF-8, if not you have to adjust accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash
function px {
 local a="$@"
 local i=0
 while [ $i -lt ${#a}  ]
  do
   printf \\x${a:$i:2}
   i=$(($i+2))
  done
}
(iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16 | od -x |  cut -b 9- | xargs -n 1) |
if read utf16header
then
 echo -e $utf16header
 out=''
 while read line
  do
   if [ "$line" == "000a" ]
    then
     out="$out $line"
     echo -e $out
     out=''
   else
    out="$out $line"
   fi
  done
 if [ "$out" != '' ] ; then
   echo -e $out
 fi
fi |
 (perl -pe 's/( 0020)* 2461 .*$/ 000a/;s/ *//g') |
 while read line
  do
    px $line
  done | (iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 )
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e "s/[[:space:]]②[^\.]*\.//"`

However, I am not sure that the ② symbol is parsed correctly. Maybe you have to use UTF8 codes or something like.

Comment: It does not seem to remove any text, even when I tried with a simpler symbol, such as a letter.

Comment: It worked for me. Which platform do you use? Maybe your sed need an option for a specific syntax.

Comment: I have `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Comment: Try to add -r (at some platforms: -E) to switch extended regex syntax.

Comment: According to the documentation, `-r` should switch on regex, but it still does not work.

Comment: But you apply the command to your file, or pipe the content to sed, don't you?

Comment: I used `sed -r -e "s/[[:space:]]②[^\.]*\.//"` file.txt`. The output shows no change.

Comment: I tested with `sed -e "s/[[:space:]]#[^\.]*\.//" file.txt` and an accordingly adopted file `file.txt`. Worked. Regarding UTF8 (I guess you mean it, not UST-8), see the anwer by pizza.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/②/ s/[ ]*②.*$//'
```

- `/②/` look only for the lines containing the magic symbol;
- `[ ]*` for any number (matches none) of spaces before the magic symbol;
- `.*$` everything else till the end of line.