# Deleting string up to the first occurrence of certain character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, replace

Is there a way to delete all the characters up to and including the first occurrence of a certain character?

```
123:abc
12:cba
1234:cccc
```

and the output would be:

```
abc
cba
cccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d":" -f2- myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*://' file
abc
cba
cccc
```

Or using awk:

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' file
abc
cba
cccc
```

Comment: Won't the first solution cut up to the *last* occurrence of the character? And the second solution cuts from 1st to 2nd (if any)?

Comment: I have included generated output also. sed removes from start 0 or more of any chars that are not a `:` and then a `:`

Answer (score 2):

If the data is in a variable, you can use parameter expansion:

```
$ var=123:abc
$ echo ${var#*:}
abc
$
```

The # means to remove the shortest pattern of `*:` (anything followed by a colon) from the front of the string, as you said in your requirement "delete all the characters up to the first occurrence of certain character + that character", not to get the second field where the delimiter is the colon.

Answer (score 1):

### use `awk`

```
echo "123:abc" | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'
```

- `-F` means to use `:` as the separator to split the string.
- `{print $2}` means to print the second substring.