# using sed, remove everything before the first occurence of a character

Tags: unix, sed

Let's say I have a line looking like this

```
Hello my first name is =Bart and my second is =Homer
```

How can I do if I want to get everything after the first `=` or `:` using `sed`?

In this example, I would like to get the result

```
Bart and my second is =Homer
```

I am using `sed 's/.*[=:]//'` right now but I get `Homer` as result (everything after the last `=` or `:`) and I would like to get everything after the first, and not the last `=` or `:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting string up to the first occurrence of certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352111/deleting-string-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-certain-character)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Normally, quantifiers in `sed` are greedy, which is why you will always match the last `=`. What defines the first `=` is that all the characters before it are not `=`, so:

```
sed 's/^[^=]*=//'
```

Your question implies that either `:` or `=` are valid markers, in which case

```
sed 's/^[^=:]*[=:]//'
```