# How do I use sed like cut -d':' -f2?

Tags: sed, puzzle

I'm trying to learn sed and cant figure this one out.
I found this:

```
sed -e ‘s/^[^=]*=//’
```

for picking up "valueA" from "valueA=value"  but the data I'm working with is this:

```
Continent:Area(sq. mi):Density(People per sq. mi)

Asia:16,920,000:225
Africa:11,730,000:76
North America:9,460,000:54
South America:6,890,000:54
Antarctica:5,300,000:0.00018
Europe:3,930,000:181
Australia:3,478,200:9.3

===========================
```

The puzzle says to use sed like 'cut -d':' -f2' and I can't seem to get it done right.

Comment: `awk -F: '{print $2}'`

Comment: it says I Have to use sed though...

Comment: What's the expected output? Did you try something with `:` instead of `=`, and what did you get?

Comment: -bash-4.2$ sed -f lab3in4.sed lab3in
    Area(sq. mi):Density(People per sq. mi)
    16,920,000:225
    11,730,000:76
    9,460,000:54
    6,890,000:54
    5,300,000:0.00018
    3,930,000:181
    3,478,200:9.3

    ===========================
    -bash-4.2$ cat lab3in4.sed
    s/^[^:]*://

    -bash-4.2$
it still shows after the : instead of cutting to the delimiter like cut -d':' -f2

Comment: `sed -e 's/^[^:]*://;s/:.*$//'` which removes the first column and then removes the rest

Comment: Duplicate of [using sed, remove everything before the first occurence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003133/using-sed-remove-everything-before-the-first-occurence-of-a-character) and [deleting string up to the first occurrence of certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352111/deleting-string-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-certain-character)

Comment: You should [edit] the question instead of adding your attempt to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/[^:]*/\n&\n/2;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p' file
```

Surround the 2nd field by newlines, then remove everything upto and including a newline as well as everything from a newline to the end of the line.