# Remove slash from ip/block address and place ip and block in a variable

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, grep

I am trying to separate the ip/block address and place the ip in a variable and the block in another. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipblock="100.100.40.160/29"
block="$(basename $ipblock)"
#ipaddress="100.100.40.160"

echo "block=\"$block\""
#echo "address=\"$ipaddress\""
```

I need the ip address equation so that the results are ...

```
block="29"
address="100.100.40.160"
```

Comment: I don't see how your link makes my question a duplicate. Somewhat same scenario but not duplicate. I could not use their answer to formulate an equation to give me the answer I was looking for. Thanks for trying.

Comment: It is marked as duplicated, because you are trying to split a string "100.100.40.160/29" by a delimiter "/". The linked SO question contains plenty of answers that would solve your task; one of them being: `address=$(echo ipblock | cut -d "/" -f 1); block=$(echo ipblock | cut -d "/" -f 2)`

Answer (score 0):

I kept research the boards here and found something similar at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170409/2186005 and it works well.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipblock="100.100.40.160/29"
block="$(basename $ipblock)"
ipaddress="${ipblock%/*}"

echo "block=\"$block\""
echo "address=\"$ipaddress\""
```

when I ran the script, I received the results I was initially looking for.

```
root@hills #/home # sh script.sh
block="29"
address="100.100.40.160"
```