# Bash - Remove all text after characters using wildcards

Tags: string, bash, trim

I saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170409/9623274) showing how you can remove all text after a character in a string in Bash. With this information, I can do something like this to round down a number:

```
NUMBER=10.12345
NUMBER=${NUMBER%.*} # 10
```

However, I want to keep two digits after the decimal. How can I get `10.12345` to be `10.12`? I don't need to properly round, just trim. Perhaps something with wildcards when running `${NUMBER%.*}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can round a float with `printf`. Try `printf "%.2f" "${NUMBER}"`. You could save the value into a variable as well: `printf -v myvar "%.2f" "${NUMBER}"`.

Comment: Oh that's convenient. Thank you, I'll mark it as correct after the 10 minute timer is up

Answer (score 1):

Using `=~` operator:

```
$ num=10.12345
$ [[ $num =~ ^[0-9]*(.[0-9]{1,2})? ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
10.12
$ num=10
$ [[ $num =~ ^[0-9]*(.[0-9]{1,2})? ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
10
```