# Why does cut not work with the output of a program?

Tags: string, bash, split, cut, stderr

I need to get the version number of a program from the following output:

```sh
~$ pyrcc5 -version
pyrcc5 v5.15.0
~$
```

Now I thought [`cut` could do the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168417/14909980):

```py
~$ pyrcc5 -version | cut -f2 -d"v"
pyrcc5 v5.15.0

~$
```

But it doesn't cut away anything ?!?

```py
~$ echo $(pyrcc5 -version) | cut -f2 -d"v"
pyrcc5 v5.15.0

~$
```

Even worse … Expected output would be

```sh
5.15.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pyrcc5 is printing the version string to stderr, not stdout. Try `pyrcc5 -version 2>&1 | cut -dv -f2`.

Comment: OMG I'm dumb not to think of _that_ - Many thanks !